# Add key vault access policy using power shell does not work

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am calling powershell script to add ADF into key vaults access policies using the following command

If I grant it through portal UI, it works. What could be wrong with the following code or should i use different Api?

```
$Id = (Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $DataFactoryName).Identity.PrincipalId
Write-Host "Add permissions to key vault"
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $AKVName -ObjectId $Id -PermissionsToSecrets Get,Set
I get this Error:Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy : 'AccessPolicies' exceeds maximum item count of '16'.
```

It should add permission to ADF for the given key vault

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. I was able to add it using UI without removing anything. I think the key valut/api version is wrong but i am not able to figure out

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer in the below post

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ee3ec74a-3103-4795-92fb-ee5ec5298d38/add-key-vault-access-policy-using-power-shell-does-not-work?forum=AzureKeyVault

Comment: ideally you are supposed to explain the answer and then the link